# How can I calculate the moving average with yahoo_fin in Python?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, stock, moving-average

I am trying to make a program that emails alerts when a stock price crosses a moving average and I am using the library `yahoo_fin` (Here are the [docs](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/))

I am trying to get the moving average data from `yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_stats('a')` but I am getting the following error:

```python
File "lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 241, in get_stats
  table.columns = ["Attribute" , "Value"]  
File "lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5287, in __setattr__
  return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)  
File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 67, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__  
File "lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 661, in _set_axis
  self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)  
File "lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 178, in set_axis
  f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "  
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

Any help on fixing this would be great!

If you don't know how to get this particular function to work, another alternative I tried and which seems to work is to use the method `yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_data('a')`, but I would need help to know how to calculate the moving average from this data.

Comment: which version of python and `yahoo_fin` are you using?  it works on `python 3.6` and `yahoo_fin 0.8.4`. Also, could you give a bit more code context? what modules are you importing?

Comment: I am using python 3.7.7 and yahoo_fin 0.8.4! I am just trying to get the get_stats('a') to work and it's giving an error with that. Once I get the get_stats('a') to show me some data then I want to get the moving average from that data. Just typing yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_stats('a') gives me the error above. I am also using import yahoo_fin & from yahoo_fin import stock_info

Comment: sorry, I'm not able to replicate the issue. it works just fine `python -c "import yahoo_fin; from yahoo_fin import stock_info; print(yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_data('a'))"`. Try a different version of pandas? which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: i am using pandas 1.0.3! i'm trying to use the get_stats('a') and not the get_data('a'). i can try get_data('a') but how would you get a 50 day moving average from that data? also, how would you make it not pick up unnecessary data in the table?

Comment: `get_stats` also works `python -c "import yahoo_fin; from yahoo_fin import stock_info; print(yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_stats('a'))"` and I am using the same version of `pandas`. Sorry

Comment: my get_data('a') works but i don't know how to get a moving average from that data. how would you get a moving average after get_data('a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate the 50 day moving average from `get_data` using the code:

```py
import yahoo_fin
from yahoo_fin import stock_info
yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_data('a', interval='1d')['close'][-50:].mean()
```

if you want yo calculate it over a certain period:

```
df = yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_data('a', interval='1d')
moving_average = [df['close'][i-50:i].mean() for i in range(50, df.shape[0]+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I pushed a patch for this - if you upgrade your version of yahoo_fin to 0.8.5, this should be fixed now.

```
from yahoo_fin import stock info as si
si.get_stats("a")
```

From this, you can get the 50-day and 200-day moving averages.  However, as mentioned in @user7440787's response, you can use the get_data method to pull the price history, and then calculate whatever window-size moving average you need to (10-day, 100-day, 150-day, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! I got `stock_info.get_stats("a").Value[5]` to work for only grabbing the 50-MA value!